# Looking for a good server side shopping cart solution

Tags: php, shopping-cart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I'm working on a website that will be selling tickets and they will go fast. I need a server side solutions, in php if possible, that will keep tickets from over selling. Any suggestions?

Also, I'm looking for the system to be more plug and play, like an API maybe. I'm not really looking for a eCommerce solution to sell goods. I need something simple and can sell tickets.

Like EventBright but for a server in php.

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/590/google-amazon-paypal-roll-your-own-shopping-cart-checkout-option-that-doesnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OSCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/) is free and it uses PHP.  I am not sure if it tracks inventory but it should.  Since it is open source you can easily mod it.  It does allow for easy purchase integration as well.  The big downside is that it is older and bulky.

Answer (score 1):

[Zen Cart](http://www.zen-cart.com/) is an alternative version of OSCommerce.

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is newer and very popular.

Answer (score 0):

I have a large site running Magento. While it is great for a total e-commerce solution, it might be to large for what you want to do. Customization can cause headaches as well if you are not familiar with the Zend Framework. Have you thought about writing something custom?