# PHP/MySQL shopping cart recommendation

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, shopping-cart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I need a shopping cart for PHP/MySQL. What I need is very simple. I have a template already set up with the 15 items that we want to sell. We don't require a storefront, only a cart that uses a gateway. The user should be able to click on the item in my template and then go to checkout.

Can someone recommend something that would meet these needs? I want to stay away from bloated apps.

Comment: You may find what you're looking for here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/looking-for-a-good-server-side-shopping-cart-solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are only selling a few dozen items with no storefront and you want simplicity, I would recommend finding a simple and cheap solution that is pre-made.  Google-Checkout might be perfect for you: http://checkout.google.com/seller/integrate.html

[update]: Google Checkout has been retired. You can no longer process orders. The last day to process refunds will be December 20, 2013.

Now see https://wallet.google/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free opensource option : [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Google checkout is really straight forward to use and setup. We used it for a large online store and it works well without problems.